Missing Maghrib salah due to not being able to pray it outside
Assalamu aleykum wa Rahmatullahi wa Barakatuh!
Just as the title suggests, today i unfortunately couldn’t perform a Maghrib prayer due to me being outside of my home, let me elaborate: In my country women are mostly prohibited from praying in mosques, yes, it’s a country where more than 70% of the population are muslim, yet historically it just happened to be like this. Thankfully, in the recent years newly built mosques allow women in as they finally started constructing masjids that also include separate areas for women. I kind of went off topic, but what i meant to say is that i couldn’t have prayed Maghrib in a masjid. Then i also asked my teacher because of whose classes i missed Maghrib a few times already if i could just pray it inside of our driving school, to which i’ve received a rejection. So please, tell me what to do in this situation. I know that there are a few conditions as to how one can make up missed salah if one is to do it unintentionally, but as you can see, this scenario doesn’t apply to this rule.
P.S: I’d love to skip these driving lessons during these blessed days of Ramadan, but i already did skip 2/3 of my weekly classes for a few weeks straights and since my graduation there is nearing, i am not allowed to skip any more, so please, advise me on what to do. At the time of me writing this, i still haven’t prayed Isha but i do have more than enough time to do so and thus i wanted to receive advice before i perform it.

In Shia Fiqh one can commit Maqrib prayer up to about 5 minutes to midnight (so if you have more than enough time for Isha, you will of course have time for Maqrib), and also people always can commit Qadha prayer to compensate the missed ones, so I guess you follow a different Fiqh and this will not help you ...

Ask for a 5 minute break to use bathroom then make wudu InshaAllah and find any place mosque or no mosque to pray at designated time of maghrib inshallah. Maybe the closet, a basement, unused rooms, etc. Pray anywhere possible/permissible, obviously not inside the bathroom as that wouldn’t be permissible I hope this is helpful sister. Ramadan Mubarak Walaykum Asalam! Inshallah make it your business to create spaces/masjid for Muslim sisters to offer salat
